# Using php curl to automate website.

Tags: php, python, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize)

Anyway to do this with curl php?

```
  import mechanize
  br=mechanize.Browser()
  br.open('https://www.google.com/calendar/exporticalzip')
  br.select_form(nr=0)
  br['Email']='Username@gmail.com'
  br['Passwd']='Password'
  br.submit()
  br.retrieve('https://www.google.com/calendar/exporticalzip','exportical.zip')
```

Comment: Mechanize and curl are not that similar, after the fact they both can retrieve HTTP-based content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize) or [Mechanize and BeautifulSoup for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263800/mechanize-and-beautifulsoup-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

Read [Using cURL to interact with Google Data services](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html).

Refer to [PHP Curl with Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090932/php-curl-with-google-calendar) and [Class: Google Calendar Wrapper](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3548-PHP-Register-events-in-Google-Calendar.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent PHP class which emulates web browsers much like curl does called [**Snoopy**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/).

It allows a lot of extra functionality like extracting links from a fetched page and  extracting form elements which might be quite useful in your case.